# My app dies when switch to another app

Tags: android

I am developing two apps:

-> App A: it connects to a Bluetooth device, retrieve some data, process this data and broadcast an intent to App B

-> App B: it receives this intent and shows the results.

App A must keep running in order to keep sending data to App B.

Everything was working fine until this week when I made some visual changes and update my android device to V7.0.

Now, My App A stops (DEAD message in debugging window in android studio) when I switch to App B and see the results. If I change back to App A, current activity restarts itself and it works normally once again.

I do not get any exception or error message in android studio's debug window.

Any idea or information about this issue. I must say I have read a lot of questions and documentation but I can not find the reason of this issue.

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: It is probably because App B needs more memory so the Android OS decides to close the background apps like in your case which is the App A. Make sure also your App A is not a memory intensive app otherwise it will consume most of the memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I do not think this is the problem, both apps use 8 - 10 MB and CPU < 0.5%. Also, I do not have any other open app which can consume more memory.

Comment: its because onPause() and onResume() check if you unregistered broadcast receiver in onPause()

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Avinash However, I am not unregistering any broadcast neither on onPause()  nor on onResume().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything was working fine until this week when I made some visual
>   changes and update my android device to V7.0.

7.0 has introduced [numerous changes aimed at improving battery life](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html). Your App A is likely suffering from these changes, particularly if it was memory / cpu intensive, which it sounds like it might be.

> App A must keep running in order to keep sending data to App B.

If that's the case, you probably want a make App A a [foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) to ensure it keeps running.

Architecturally this probably makes more sense anyway if your use case is to have App B open while App A keeps piping data to it. The fact that your App A was not dying before was likely just lucky chance. It would have been killed by the system eventually after going into the background.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your comments make so much sense and I will create next version with foreground services. However, I do not have time to change the whole app. Furthermore, I have run both apps for hours beside other apps without problems.

Comment: Of course it's possible there's another reason for the behavior you're seeing, but based on your description that's my best guess. Make sure you didn't accidentally turn on "Kill Activities" developer option which would instantly kill your activity when switching from one to the other. Is the behavior consistent on devices and emulators? API versions?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, your guess is the same as mine. I do not have that option activated. 

Yes, this behavior is consistent on all devices and emulators. Actually, App A has been moved from Eclipse to Android Studio one month ago and both versions have the same behavior. I know, it is a weird issue.

Comment: I managed to implement foregrounds easily and without big changes.

Even when I did not find an answer for my issue, @dominicoder 's answer helped me as a walkoround.